# Getting a snap shot from video view class

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I'm trying to use the `MediaMetadataRetriever` class to take a snapshot of a video stream.
I want to use the following method:

```
retriever.setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri);
```

what do I need to put in context when I call the method?

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Context context, Uri uri){
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(context context,uri.toString());
    return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
}
```